# Oracle Trigger with UPDATE OF ( column name identical with table)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, database-trigger

i have a problem with my column who has the same name as one of my tables.
I can not use table.column in this situation

repres was a table in the windev database and a column in commerc database and devent table where i create this trigger

When i do : `AFTER UPDATE OF etat,total, devent.repres`
I Have :
ERROR line 2, col 35, ending_line 2, ending_col 35, Found '.', Expecting:  ,   or  ON  OR

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER WINDEV_AES_UPDATE
AFTER UPDATE OF etat,total, repres
ON COMMERC.DEVENT
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

BEGIN

  IF UPDATING AND :OLD.etat != :NEW.etat THEN
  INSERT INTO windev.aes (code) 
  SELECT (:NEW.CODE)
  FROM DUAL
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM windev.aes WHERE code = :NEW.CODE);

  UPDATE windev.aes SET aes.update_flag = 1 WHERE aes.code = :NEW.CODE; 
  END IF;

  IF UPDATING AND :OLD.total != :NEW.total THEN
  INSERT INTO windev.aes (code) 
  SELECT (:NEW.CODE)
  FROM DUAL
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM windev.aes WHERE code = :NEW.CODE);

  UPDATE windev.aes SET aes.update_flag = 1 WHERE aes.code = :NEW.CODE; 
  END IF;



END;
/
```

I hope you tell me how resolve this epic problem ;-)

Comment: There is nothing after Declare, you meant to declare something there ? if not erase it. and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582720/how-to-trigger-when-multiple-columns-are-updated

Comment: Do you really have a column called `repres` in `COMMERC.DEVENT` table ?

Comment: Yes, in `COMMERC.DEVENT` i have a column called `repres` and the company use this since few years, i can't change it.

Comment: Ok i have remove `DECLARE`and they seem good.