# Trigger conflict PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, conflict

These 3 tables are connected, using *short-circuit keys*, ID_KOEFICIJENT is in table RADNIK through table RADNO_MESTO. And I have a problem with triggers. I think it's a conflict between triggers. When I want to update the table RADNIK, for example:

```
update radnik set ID_KOEFICIJENT=3, prezime_ime='Perica Milisav', datum_rodjenja='2020-03-23', 
zanimanje='astronaut', id_radno_mesto=3,stepen_strucne_spreme='7.3', identifikator_casova_rada=7 
where ID_RADNIK=10;
```

It will update everything except ID_KOEFICIJENT but it won't give back a message from trigger **UIK_RADNIK** if I change ID_KOEFICIJENT to 4,5,6,7... .

Table RADNIK: **Primary key**: ID_RADNIK, **Foreign keys**: ID_KOEFICIJENT and ID_RADNO_MESTO

```
CREATE TABLE "RADNIK"(
"ID_RADNIK" NUMBER(*,0), 
"JMBG" NUMBER(*,0), 
"PREZIME_IME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"DATUM_RODJENJA" DATE, 
"ZANIMANJE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"STEPEN_STRUCNE_SPREME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"IDENTIFIKATOR_CASOVA_RADA" NUMBER(*,0), 
"ID_KOEFICIJENT" NUMBER(*,0), 
"ID_RADNO_MESTO" NUMBER
```

)

Table RADNO_MESTO: **Primary key**: ID_RADNO_MESTO, **Foreign key**: ID_KOEFICIJENT

```
CREATE TABLE "RADNO_MESTO"(
"ID_RADNO_MESTO" NUMBER(*,0), 
"NAZIV" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
"BR_IZVRSILACA" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0, 
"DATUM_OD" DATE, 
"DATUM_DO" DATE, 
"ID_KOEFICIJENT" NUMBER(*,0)
)
```

Table KOEFICIJENT: **Primary key**: ID_KOEFICIJENT

```
CREATE TABLE "KOEFICIJENT"(
"ID_KOEFICIJENT" NUMBER(*,0), 
"BROJ" FLOAT(126), 
"DATUM_OD" DATE, 
"DATUM_DO" DATE
)
```

This trigger restricts directly updating column ID_KOEFICIJENT in table RADNIK.
Trigger: UIK_RADNIK:

```
create or replace TRIGGER UIK_RADNIK
BEFORE UPDATE OF ID_KOEFICIJENT ON RADNIK 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if :new.ID_KOEFICIJENT <> :old.ID_KOEFICIJENT then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Zabranjeno direktno ažuriranje koeficijenta radnika!');
    END IF;
END;
```

This trigger updates column ID_KOEFICIJENT in table RADNIK by using column ID_RADNO_MESTO.
Trigger: UIK_RADNO_MESTO:

```
create or replace TRIGGER UIK_RADNO_MESTO 
AFTER UPDATE OF ID_KOEFICIJENT ON RADNO_MESTO 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER UIK_RADNIK DISABLE';
        UPDATE RADNIK
        SET ID_KOEFICIJENT = :NEW.ID_KOEFICIJENT
        WHERE ID_RADNO_MESTO = :NEW.ID_RADNO_MESTO;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER UIK_RADNIK ENABLE';
END;
```

Trigger: UIRM_RADNIK:

```
create or replace TRIGGER UIRM_RADNIK 
BEFORE UPDATE OF ID_RADNO_MESTO ON RADNIK 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    v_id_koeficijent NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT ID_KOEFICIJENT INTO v_id_koeficijent
    FROM RADNO_MESTO
    WHERE ID_RADNO_MESTO = :NEW.ID_RADNO_MESTO;
    :NEW.ID_KOEFICIJENT := v_id_koeficijent;
END;
```

Comment: You should consider to put all the logic into PL/SQL procedures rather than in triggers. Will make you life easier.

Comment: Well, I believe that, but this is a student project with defined requirements, where I must use triggers.

Comment: What exactly is the task you must solve? With the triggers you have, I'd say that your update can never change ID_KOEFICIJENT (except for NULL). Either the column remains the same or you get an exception. Which of the two depends on the values in your update and which of the two RADNIK triggers Oracle happens to perform first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set execution precedence in your triggers:

[Order of execution of trigger and statements in Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693502/order-of-execution-of-trigger-and-statements-in-oracle-stored-procedure#17694591)

And you can unify UIK_RADNIK and UIRM_RADNIK triggers too:

[how to trigger when multiple columns are updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582720/how-to-trigger-when-multiple-columns-are-updated)